# C# data design for variable type dictionary value

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, design-patterns, database-design

I have a design right now where I want a dictionary that gives me some values that could be of different types. My idea would be to have some interface that would represent a potential value type so then I could implement the interface. My problem is that if I make a generic interface then I can't have the dictionary return multiple types of the interface. If I make variable interface methods, then I can't implement them properly in the wrapper classes. Does anyone have a good solution to have a dictionary with variable value types?

Comment: `Dictionary<int, object> or Dictionary<int, dynamic>`

Comment: `Dictionary<T, dynamic>` or `Dictionary<T, object>`?

Comment: You've glossed over a lot of details. You mentioned generics and wrapper classes but not why they won't work, and you haven't actually explained what you're trying to accomplish, only the mechanism you're using. This is sometimes a sign of an XY problem. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

Comment: "My problem is that if I make a generic interface then I can't have the dictionary return multiple types of the interface" I am not sure this is true because I am not sure what you mean. Could you maybe post a short snippet of code to clarify what you want to be able to do?